# Sinatra with a persistent variable

Tags: ruby, sinatra, scope

My sinatra app has to parse a ~60MB XML-file. This file hardly ever changes: on a nightly cron job, It is overwritten with another one.

Are there tricks or ways to keep the parsed file in memory, as a variable, so that I can read from it on incoming requests, but not have to parse it over and over for each incoming request?

Some Pseudocode to illustrate my problem.

```
get '/projects/:id'
  return @nokigiri_object.search("//projects/project[@id=#{params[:id]}]/name/text()")
end

post '/projects/update'
  if params[:token] == "s3cr3t"
    @nokogiri_object = reparse_the_xml_file
  end
end
```

What I need to know, is how to create such a @nokogiri_object so that it persists when Sinatra runs. Is that possible at all? Or do I need some storage for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
configure do
  @@nokogiri_object = parse_xml
end
```

Then `@@nokogiri_object` will be available in your request methods. It's a class variable rather than an instance variable, but should do what you want.

Comment: Will @@var be avaialable across sessions and across requests? Say user Anna fetches /foo, @@var is created, then, when Barry visits /foo, @@var is still set?

Comment: @berkes yes there's just one `@@var` shared between all requests

Comment: @berkes: Having a variable of 60 mb is not very efficient. That ram should be put to better use. I think the solution of using a file to store the parsed file is much better. You could even use a Mini redis database to store just the last time the file was parsed or even use a global variable for that. But store in memory just the date, not the actual file. If it is longer than one day, then update the parsed file. If it is lower then just read the parsed file. That is the most efficient way I can think of.

Comment: @@Nerian: you are correct. And in the first refactoring I will consider either redis or mongodb. For now, I mostly need to get a proof of concept up, seeing if I can parse the file/files (there are many more) based on the parameters. But thanks for the warning and tip!

Comment: @Dominik you mean the method is called on each _request_? Are you using shotgun or some other app reloader?

Comment: @matt yes that was the problem. it's working, thanks for the hint! maybe add this to your answer :)

Answer (score 9):

The proposed solution gives a warning

> warning: class variable access from toplevel

You can use a class method to access the class variable and the warning will disappear

```
require 'sinatra'

class Cache
  @@count = 0

  def self.init()
    @@count = 0
  end

  def self.increment()
    @@count = @@count + 1
  end

  def self.count()
    return @@count
  end
end

configure do
  Cache::init()
end

get '/' do
  if Cache::count() == 0
    Cache::increment()
    "First time"
  else
    Cache::increment()
    "Another time #{Cache::count()}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Save the parsed file to a new file and always read that one.

You can save in a file – serialize - a hash with two keys: 'last-modified' and 'data'.

The 'last-modified' value is a date and you check in every request if that day is today. If it is not today then a new file is downloaded, parsed and stored with today's date.

The 'data' value is the parsed file.

That way you parse just once time, sort of a cache.

- Save the parsed file to a NoSQL database, for example redis.

Comment: I have been thinking about redis, memcached or even mongoDB indeed. Still in the race, but I'd prefer to keep it really-really simple when possible :)