# Ruby add method to a class

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Assume I have a class :

```
class Foo
end
```

To add a method to this class I know 2 options:

1. Reopening the class and implement the method :

   ```
   class Foo
     def bar
     end
   end
   ```
2. using `class_eval` to implement method :

   ```
   Foo.class_eval { def bar; end}
   ```

What is the difference? Which one is better?

Comment: [`Foo#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) also.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually, there are a few other ways to add new methods to a class. For example, you can also define the methods in a module, and mix the module into the original class.

```
module ExtraMethods
  def bar
  end
end

Foo.class_eval { include ExtraMethods }
class Foo
  include ExtraMethods
end
```

There is no real better or worse. The two (or three) ways you mentioned have different behavior and you may want to use one or another depending on your need (or preference). In most cases, this is subjective. In other cases, it really depends on how your code is structured.

The main objective difference between reopening the class vs using `class_eval` is that the first one is also a class definition, whereas the second one requires the original class to already be defined.

In practice, reopening the class in some cases may cause some unexpected side effects. Let's suppose you defined `Foo` in the file `lib/foo.rb`, with a bunch of methods. Then you reopen `Foo` in `config/initializers/extra.rb` and you add the `bar` method.

In `myclass.rb` you use `Foo`, but instead of requiring `lib/foo.rb` manually, you rely on an autoload feature.

If `extra.rb` is loaded before `lib/foo.rb`, what could happen is that the `Foo` class is already defined in your environment, and your code will not load `lib/foo.rb`. What you will have is a `Foo` class containing only the `bar` extension you defined, and not the original `Foo` one.

In other words, if for whatever reason you reopen the class to add some methods without making sure the full origina class definition is loaded first (or after), your code may break if it relies on autoload.

Conversely, `Foo.class_eval` calls a method on `Foo`, therefore it expects the original `Foo` definition to be already present at the time you try to add new methods. This ensures that, when you add new methods, the `Foo` class will already be defined.

In conclusion, the main difference is that reopening the class allows you (for better or for worse) to add methods to a class that may not have been loaded yet, whereas the `class_eval` requires the class to already be defined.

In general, unless I'm defining namespaced subclasses or reopening classes I have full control of, I prefer the second approach as in large codebases it keeps the code more maintainable. In fact, I generally use mixins if I extend third-party classes so that I can retain the full method ancestor chain if I need to override existing methods.

Comment: There is no “Ruby autoload,” you probably meant “Rails autoload.”

Comment: @mudasobwa technically there is (the `autoload` method), but it would not apply to this case. I made a small change to the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

The second approach is very handy when you need some dynamic thing. Ruby actually has several scopes:

```
# scope one, opened with `class` keyword
class ...
  # scope two, opened with `def` keyword
  def ...
  end
end
```

With `class_eval`, you can share scopes.

```
>> foo = 1
=> 1
>> class Foo
>>   puts foo
>>   def bar
>>     puts foo
>>   end
>> end
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'foo' for Foo:Class
        from (irb):3:in <class:Foo>
        from (irb):2
>> Foo
=> Foo
>> Foo.class_eval {
?>   puts foo
>>   define_method :bar do
>>     puts foo
>>   end
>> }
1
=> :bar
>> Foo.new.bar
1
```

Comment: But this also means that this shared scope will not be garbage-collected while class exists