# How to set a class variable from a class-level method when using Class.new?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I recall reading somewhere that the following two pieces of code are identical in Ruby.

```
# Number 1
class A
  # body
end

# Number 2
A = Class.new
  # body
end
```

However I noticed that when I try to set a class variable from a class-level method, the two syntaxes produce different results.

With the first syntax, the variable is set on the class itself as expected.

```
irb(main):001:0> class A
irb(main):002:1>   def self.foo
irb(main):003:2>     @@a = :banana
irb(main):004:2>   end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> :foo
irb(main):006:0> A.class_variables
=> []
irb(main):007:0> A.foo
=> :banana
irb(main):008:0> A.class_variables
=> [:@@a]
irb(main):009:0> A.class_variable_get :@@a
=> :banana

irb(main):010:0> Class.class_variable_get :@@a
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@a in Class
    from (irb):10:in `class_variable_get'
    from (irb):10
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):011:0>
```

With the second, the variable gets set on `Class` itself!

```
irb(main):015:0> K = Class.new do
irb(main):016:1*   def self.foo
irb(main):017:2>     @@k = :banana
irb(main):018:2>   end
irb(main):019:1> end
=> K
irb(main):020:0> K.class_variables
=> []
irb(main):021:0> K.foo
(irb):17: warning: class variable access from toplevel
=> :banana
irb(main):022:0> K.class_variables
=> [:@@k]
irb(main):023:0> K.class_variable_get :@@k
=> :banana
irb(main):024:0> Class.class_variable_get :@@k
=> :banana
```

Why does this happen?

In what I am working on, I have to generate a class dynamically, so I have no choice but to use the second syntax. As such, how do I ensure that the variable `@@k` gets set on the new `Class` object being defined, and not on `Class` itself?

Comment: I dunno the reason exactly but if you use class instance variables (single @, but in class scope), it seems to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712458/119622 in the second case, its being set on Object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two pieces are not identical, there are differences in lexical scoping of the declarations.

In the first definition, the more common class declaration, definitions are lexically scoped to class `A`, so the class variable is set on A. Only A and classes that inherit from `A` will have that class variable.  Since `Class` **does not** inherit  from A, it doesn't  get the class variable.

In the second definition, the dynamic class assignment, the definitions are lexically scoped to top level object, which is object. So a class variable will be set on `Object`, the class of the top level object.

Now, this has huge implications. Every object inherits from Object and every class is an instance of the class `Class`, you're defining a class variable on **each and every class in your object space**.  Hence,  A gets the class variable, and `Class` gets it as well.  Try defining a new class `F`, and it will have it as well.  This is why Ruby screams the warning:

> class variable access from toplevel

This is one of reasons why class variables are typically avoided.

There are multiple ways to solve this.  My favourite is, using the `attr_accessor` on the class instance:

```
K = Class.new do
  class << self
    attr_accessor :fruit
  end

  self.fruit = :banana
end

K.fruit
# => :banana

# The value isn't shared between inherited classes,
# but the variable is:

class L < K
end

L.fruit
# => nil

L.fruit = :mango
# => :mango

K.fruit
# => :banana
```

Edit:

Keep in mind, that these variables are still not thread-safe, and are shared by all threads.  You will need thread-local variables for ensuring thread-safety.